# Validation issue in email for minimum length in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using below regex to validate the email and its working fine in most of the scenarios. But even though I specified the minimum length of the email as 5 It is accepting 2 as minimum length.So where do i change this in order to accept minimum length as 5 chars

```
(?=^.{5,254}$)(^(?!.*__.*)[a-z0-9]+(_?)*[a-z0-9]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&*+/=?^`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?$)
```

I specified minimum and max length at the beginning of regex

Comment: i dont think anyone is going to debug this regex. There are easier ways to test if the length is big enough. Like string.length.... Also it's generally a good idea to break validation regex into smaller groups one doing one thing. More maintainable and easier to debug.

Comment: Don't use regex to validate emails. Perform a few basic tests (does it have an `@` symbol followed by some characters and a dot and then some more characters?) then send them a verification email—that's the beauty of using emails.

Comment: This is some seriously messed up regex. Where did it come from? _If_ you want to use regex to validate an email, there are thousands of well-tested examples online. There's no need to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems there is a  problem in the way you have positioned the min max limit:

```
(^(?!.*__.*)[a-z0-9]{4,253}(_?)[a-z0-9]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&*+\/=?^`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?$)
```

demo here: https://regex101.com/r/dG7vZ8/1

the min length allowed here is 5 chars

you can see `{4,253}` written as the latter part of the regex matches with one character always before the @ symbol

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using lookarounds in your regular expression. As far as I know, some of these are not allowed / supported by javascript, thus are not recognized by the parser.

You might also want to shorten your regex. I think an email-regex could be much shorter, like:

`[a-z0-9!#$%&*+/=?^{|}~-.]+@[a-z0-9!#$%&*+/=?^{|}~-.]+`